# Open Outlook 2016 with a given non-default profile with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, outlook, profile

I have a VBScript which opens Outlook 2016 and sends a message.

The problem I have is that I have several Outlook profiles.

I would like to set the actual profile I wish to open from which to send the message.

My existing script is:

```
Dim objOutlook, objEmail

Dim strEmailReceiver, strEmailCc, strEmailBcc, strEmailSubject, strEmailBody, strEmailAttachments

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

strEmailSubject=InPutBox("Input your message")
With objEmail

    .To = "here@there.com"
    ' .Cc = strEmailCc
    ' .Bcc = strEmailBcc

    .Subject = strEmailSubject

    ' .Body = strEmailBody

    ' If (strEmailAttachments <> "") Then
    '   .Attachments.Add strEmailAttachments
    ' End If

    .Send

End With


'Clear the memory

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objEmail = Nothing
```

I wish to use the profile called CEO

If outlook is closed, I get a messagebox asking which profile to use, once selected the script works.  This is the step I wish to avoid.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.logon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after creating an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object, add code like the following

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
set objNS = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNS.Logon("The Profile name")
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
```

keep in mind that if Outlook is already running, `Namespace.Logon` will do nothing and you will end up with the running instance of Outlook (since it is a singleton) using whatever profile it was using at the moment

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, that is exactly what I wanted, regards John

Comment: @Vulka - if the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, more than happy to do that but I cant see how I do that, it's probably right there but I cant see it.

Comment: There is  checkbox to the left of my answer that only the original poster (you) can check.